# Calculate rotation needed to transform plane

Tags: math, 3d, isometric

I'm currently trying to render a polygon mesh in isometric (html5 canvas 2d context).
My work is almost done except I cannot find the right calculation/algorithm to find the plane rotation.

In example I have plane A and B defined by 2 vector Ox, Oy

```
var planeA = {
    Ox: {
        x: 1,
        y: -2,
        x: 1,
    }, Oy: {
        x: 1,
        y: -1,
        z: 0,
    }
}

var planeB = {
    Ox: {
        x: 0,
        y: 1,
        x: 0,
    }, Oy: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: -1,
    }
}
```

I want to find alpha (rotation around Ox), beta (rotation around Oy) and gamma (rotation around Oz) to apply on plane A to make plane A have the same normal with plane B.

Comment: Do you plan to apply the rotations in that order? Also, you need only two rotations, not three, so do you prefer efficiency or clarity?

Comment: Does the order matter (I'm not very good at math...)? And if I need only two rotation, I can leave one zero :D Just want a way to calculate that programmatically.

Comment: I was wrong: three needed. Writing up an answer...

Comment: And angle from Ox to Oy is always 90 degree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find the normals by taking the cross-product of the vectors and then normalizing.

To take the cross-product of two vectors, **A** and **B**, use this formula:

C<sub>x</sub> =  A<sub>y</sub>*B<sub>z</sub> - A<sub>z</sub>*B<sub>y</sub>
C<sub>y</sub> = -A<sub>x</sub>*B<sub>z</sub> + A<sub>z</sub>*B<sub>x</sub>
C<sub>z</sub> =  A<sub>x</sub>*B<sub>y</sub> - A<sub>y</sub>*B<sub>x</sub>

(Notice that the order matters. In general, **A**x**B** ≠ **B**x**A**.)

So for your two planes, the cross-products are (1,1,1) and (-1,0,0).

To normalize a vector, divide it by its magnitude. So the normal vectors of your planes are (1/sqrt(3))(1,1,1) and (-1,0,0).

Now to rotate on vector into another (I will assume you have `atan2()`, and that you have the right-hand rule down cold):

**1. Rotate around O<sub>x</sub>:** to get **A** into the XZ plane, rotate by atan2(A<sub>y</sub>, A<sub>z</sub>).
**2. Rotate around O<sub>y</sub>:** to get to the correct phi (angle from O<sub>z</sub>)). Phi<sub>B</sub> is atan2(sqrt(B<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup>+B<sub>y</sub><sup>2</sup>), B<sub>z</sub>), so rotate by atan2(sqrt(B<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup>+B<sub>y</sub><sup>2</sup>), B<sub>z</sub>) - atan2(A<sub>x</sub>, A<sub>z</sub>)
**3. Rotate around O<sub>z</sub>:** to get to the correct "longitude", rotate by atan2(B<sub>y</sub>, B<sub>x</sub>) - atan2(A<sub>y</sub>, A<sub>x</sub>).

So in your example, you would rotate **A** around **O<sub>x</sub>** by π/4 to get (sqrt(2/3), 0, sqrt(1/3)), then around **O<sub>y</sub>** by π/2 - atan(sqrt(2)) to get (1,0,0), then around **O<sub>z</sub>** by π to get (-1,0,0).

Comment: and is it possible to make Ox, Oy of A share the same direction with Ox, Oy of B?

Comment: @hope_is_grim: Yes, of course, but it changes the problem. I assumed that these rotations were around the fixed axes of your coordinate system, not vectors imbedded in the planes; is that correct? If so, can you make a rotation around an arbitrary vector?